# Six Nations Prediction league Web App

Tags: python, javascript, html, flask, neo4j

I built a simple web app to manage my friends and I's six nation prediction league. This is my first go at web development so although it works I am guessing that I am not following all best practices or conventions. Any tips would be much appreciated.

The stack I used is:

Neo4j <-> Py2Neo <-> Flask <-> Html, JS, CSS

I know it would have been simpler to do with just a standard sql database but I wanted to learn a graph database.

App.py - Handles the requests and calls functions that return strings of html

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, session
import yaTemplates as Templates
import NeoInterface as Neo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'MySecretKey'

def checkpassword(username, password):
    actualpassword = Neo.getpassword(username)
    if actualpassword == password:
        return True
    return False


@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return redirect('/LeagueTable')
    return Templates.login()

@app.route('/LeagueTable')
def leaguetable():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect('/')
    return Templates.leaguetable(session["username"])

@app.route('/Predictions')
def predictions():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect('/')
    return Templates.predictions(session["username"])

@app.route('/Results')
def results():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect('/')
    return Templates.results(session["username"])

@app.route('/Spread')
def spread():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return redirect('/')
    return Templates.spread(session["username"])

@app.route('/PredictionSubmit', methods=["POST"])
def predictionsubmit():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return "Failure"
    auser = session["username"]
    ateam = request.form['ateam']
    afixtureid = request.form['afixtureid']
    margin = str(request.form['margin'])
    check = Neo.mergeprediction(auser, ateam, afixtureid, margin)
    if check == "Cheat":
        return "Cheat"
    return "Success"

@app.route('/ResultSubmit', methods=["POST"])
def resultsubmit():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return "Failure"
    auser = session["username"]
    afixtureid = request.form['afixtureid']
    margin = str(request.form['margin'])
    check = Neo.mergeresult(auser, afixtureid, margin)
    return "Success"

@app.route("/loginsubmit", methods=["POST"])
def loginsubmit():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    if checkpassword(username, password):
        session.permanent = True
        session['username'] = username
        return url_for('leaguetable')
    else:
        return "Error"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

-- This contains some functions I just used in the console to set things up. The rest are used by the app.

NeoInterface.py  -- functions for interacting with Neo4j database using py2neo

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, Subgraph
from py2neo.ogm import GraphObject, Property, RelatedTo, RelatedFrom
from DataWarehouse import importcsvlistdicts
import os
from datetime import datetime

uri = "bolt://hobby-opbcljlkjmgggbkeoiobbhel.dbs.graphenedb.com:24787"
user = "Admin"
pwd = "MyPassword"
g = Graph(uri, auth=(user, pwd), secure=True)

class User(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "Username"
    Username = Property()
    Password = Property()
    League = Property()
    Predicts = RelatedTo("Prediction", "PREDICTS")

class Fixture(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "GameID"
    GameID = Property()
    ResultsEntered = Property()
    HomePoints = Property()
    Round = Property()
    Time = Property()
    AwayPoints = Property()
    Date = Property()
    Name = Property()
    In_Fixture = RelatedFrom("Prediction", "IN_FIXTURE")
    Home_Team = RelatedTo("Team", "HOME_TEAM")
    Away_Team = RelatedTo("Team", "AWAY_TEAM")

class Team(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "Name"
    Name = Property()
    PrimaryColour = Property()
    SecondaryColour = Property()
    To_Win = RelatedFrom("Prediction", "TO_WIN")
    Home_Team = RelatedFrom("Fixture", "HOME_TEAM")
    Away_Team = RelatedFrom("Fixture", "AWAY_TEAM")

class Prediction(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "ConcCat"
    ConcCat = Property()
    Margin = Property()
    Predicts = RelatedFrom("User", "PREDICTS")
    To_Win = RelatedTo("Team", "TO_WIN")
    In_Fixture = RelatedTo("Fixture", "IN_FIXTURE")

def createfromcsv(filename):
    # list of dicts where Label is reserved for label
    # todo use the filename if Label column not present
    rows = importcsvlistdicts(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename + '.csv'))
    nodelist = list()
    for arow in rows:
        thisnode = Node(arow["Label"])
        for key, value in arow.items():
            if key not in ['Label']:
                thisnode[key] = value
        nodelist.append(thisnode)
    for n in nodelist:
        g.create(n)

def mergeprediction(auser, ateam, afixtureid, margin, check=True):
    # Todo: Learn python string subsitition and swap for below
    datenow = datetime.now()
    # datenow = datetime.strptime('01/02/2020 14:16', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    cypherstatement = "MATCH (f:Fixture { GameID : '%s'}) " % afixtureid
    cypherstatement += " RETURN f.Date, f.Time "
    dateandtime = g.run(cypherstatement).data()[0]
    fixturedatetime = datetime.strptime(dateandtime["f.Date"] + ' ' + dateandtime["f.Time"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    if datenow > fixturedatetime and check:
        return "Cheat"

    tx = g.begin()
    ConcCat = auser + afixtureid
    cypherstatement = 'MATCH (p:Prediction {ConcCat:"' + ConcCat + '"}) '
    cypherstatement += ' DETACH DELETE p'
    g.run(cypherstatement)
    cypherstatement = 'CREATE (p:Prediction { ConcCat: "' + ConcCat + '", Margin: "' + margin + '"})'
    tx.run(cypherstatement)
    cypherstatement = 'MATCH (p:Prediction), (t:Team), (f:Fixture), (u:User) '
    cypherstatement += ' WHERE p.ConcCat = "' + ConcCat + '" '
    cypherstatement += ' AND t.Name = "' + ateam + '" '
    cypherstatement += ' AND f.GameID = "' + afixtureid + '" '
    cypherstatement += ' AND u.Username = "' + auser + '" '
    cypherstatement += ' CREATE '
    cypherstatement += ' (p)-[:TO_WIN]->(t), '
    cypherstatement += ' (p)-[:IN_FIXTURE]->(f), '
    cypherstatement += ' (u)-[:PREDICTS]->(p)'
    tx.run(cypherstatement)
    tx.commit()
    return "Honest"


def mergeresult(auser, afixtureid, margin):
    margin = int(margin)
    if margin < 0:
        homescore = margin * -1
        awayscore = 0
    elif margin > 0:
        homescore = 0
        awayscore = margin
    else:
        homescore = 0
        awayscore = 0
    cypherstatement = "MATCH (f:Fixture { GameID : '%s'}) " % afixtureid
    cypherstatement += " set f.HomePoints = '%d' , f.AwayPoints = '%d'" % (homescore, awayscore)
    g.run(cypherstatement)
    return "Honest"


def linkfixturetoteam(fixid, home, away):
    fixturenode = Fixture.match(g, fixid).first()
    homenode = Team.match(g, home).first()
    awaynode = Team.match(g, away).first()
    fixturenode.HomeTeam.add(homenode)
    fixturenode.AwayTeam.add(awaynode)
    g.push(fixturenode)
    g.push(homenode)
    g.push(awaynode)

def linkfixturestoteams():
    rows = importcsvlistdicts(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Fixtures" + '.csv'))
    for row in rows:
        home = row["Home"]
        away = row["Away"]
        fixid = row["GameID"]
        linkfixturetoteam(fixid, home, away)

def getpassword(auser):
    usernode = User.match(g, auser).first()
    return usernode.Password

def setpassword(auser, password):
    usernode = User.match(g, auser).first()
    usernode.Password = password
    g.push(usernode)

def setcolour(ateam, colour, seccolour):
    ateam = Team.match(g, ateam).first()
    ateam.PrimaryColour = colour
    ateam.SecondaryColour = seccolour
    g.push(ateam)

def generateficturetable(username):
    cypherstatement = "match (f:Fixture)-[:HOME_TEAM]->(h:Team), (f)-[:AWAY_TEAM]->(a:Team) "
    cypherstatement += "optional match (f)<-[:IN_FIXTURE]-(p:Prediction)<-[:PREDICTS]-(u:User {Username: '" + username + "'}) "
    cypherstatement += ", (p:Prediction)-[:TO_WIN]->(w:Team) "
    cypherstatement += " return f, h, a, p, u, w "
    returndata = g.run(cypherstatement).data()
    return returndata

def generateresultstable():
    cypherstatement = "match (f:Fixture)-[:HOME_TEAM]->(h:Team), (f)-[:AWAY_TEAM]->(a:Team) "
    cypherstatement += " return f, h, a"
    returndata = g.run(cypherstatement).data()
    return returndata

def getspreadfixture(userleague):
    datenow = datetime.now()
    # datenow = datetime.strptime('01/02/2020 14:16', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    cypherstatement = "MATCH (f:Fixture)-[:HOME_TEAM]->(h:Team), "
    cypherstatement += " (f:Fixture)-[:AWAY_TEAM]->(a:Team) "
    cypherstatement += " return f, h, a"
    returndata = g.run(cypherstatement).data()
    mindiff = 24 * 30
    minfixture = None
    for afixture in returndata:
        fixturedate = datetime.strptime(afixture['f']["Date"] + ' ' + afixture['f']["Time"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
        datediff = (datenow - fixturedate).total_seconds() / 3600
        if 0 < datediff < mindiff:
            minfixture = afixture
            mindiff = datediff
    if minfixture is None:
        return None, None
    cypherstatement = " MATCH (f:Fixture {GameID : '" + minfixture['f']["GameID"] + "'})"
    cypherstatement += "<-[:IN_FIXTURE]-(p:Prediction)-[:TO_WIN]->(t:Team),  "
    cypherstatement += "(p:Prediction)<-[:PREDICTS]-(u:User) "
    cypherstatement += ' where u.League = "' + userleague + '"'
    cypherstatement += " return p, t, u"
    predictions = g.run(cypherstatement).data()
    return minfixture, predictions

def getleaguedata(userleague):
    cypherstatement = "MATCH (f:Fixture)-[:HOME_TEAM]->(h:Team), "
    cypherstatement += " (f:Fixture)-[:AWAY_TEAM]->(a:Team) "
    cypherstatement += " return f, h, a"
    fixtures = g.run(cypherstatement).data()
    cypherstatement = " MATCH (f:Fixture)"
    cypherstatement += "<-[:IN_FIXTURE]-(p:Prediction)-[:TO_WIN]->(t:Team),  "
    cypherstatement += "(p:Prediction)<-[:PREDICTS]-(u:User) "
    cypherstatement += ' where u.League = "' + userleague + '"'
    cypherstatement += " return f, p, t, u"
    predictions = g.run(cypherstatement).data()
    return fixtures, predictions

def getusers(userleague):
    cypherstatement = "MATCH (u:User)"
    cypherstatement += ' where u.League = "' + userleague + '"'
    cypherstatement += " return u"
    users = g.run(cypherstatement).data()
    return users

def getuserleague(auser):
    cypherstatement = 'MATCH (u:User) where u.Username = "' + auser + '" return u.League'
    return g.run(cypherstatement).data()[0]['u.League']
```

YaTemplates.py  -- Uses Yattag library to generate html

```py
from yattag import Doc, indent
import os
import NeoInterface as Neo
from datetime import datetime
from GameLogic import *

def padstrings(astring, padtonum, alignment):
    astringlength = len(astring)
    numspacestoadd = padtonum - astringlength
    left = False
    if alignment == "Left":
        left = True
    for x in range(0, numspacestoadd):
        if left:
            astring = astring + ' '
        else:
            astring = ' ' + astring
        if alignment == "Center":
            left = not left
    return astring


def gettextfromfile(afilename):
    afilename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), afilename)
    with open(afilename) as f:
        return f.read()

def materialize(innerHTML, headeradditions=''):
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    doc.asis("<!DOCTYPE html>")
    with tag('head'):
        doc.stag('link', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons', rel='stylesheet')
        doc.stag('link', rel='stylesheet',
                 href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css')
        doc.stag('meta', name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
        with tag('script'):
            doc.attr(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js')
        doc.asis(indent(headeradditions, indent_text=True))
    with tag('html'):
        with tag('body'):
            doc.asis(indent(innerHTML, indent_text=True))
    return indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)

def addmenu(innerhtml):
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    with tag('div', klass='row'):
        text('')
    with tag("center"):
        with tag('div', klass='row'):
            with tag('a', klass='waves-effect waves-light btn', href='LeagueTable'):
                text("Table")
            with tag('a', klass='waves-effect waves-light btn', href='Predictions'):
                text("Predictions")
            with tag('a', klass='waves-effect waves-light btn', href='Results'):
                text("Results")
            with tag('a', klass='wave-effect waves-light btn', href='Spread'):
                text('Spread')
    doc.asis(indent(innerhtml, indent_text=True))
    return indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)

def leaguetable(username):
    usersleague = Neo.getuserleague(username)
    users = Neo.getusers(usersleague)
    scoresdict = dict()
    for user in users:
        scoresdict[user["u"]["Username"]] = 0
    fixtures, predictions2 = Neo.getleaguedata(usersleague)
    fixturepredictions = dict()
    for f in fixtures:
        fixturepredictions[f["f"]["GameID"]] = []
    for x in predictions2:
        pred = [x['u']['Username'], x['t']['Name'], x['p']['Margin']]
        gameid = x["f"]["GameID"]
        fixturepredictions[gameid].append(pred)
    for f in fixtures:
        winningmargin = int(f["f"]["AwayPoints"]) - int(f["f"]["HomePoints"])
        preds = fixturepredictions[f["f"]["GameID"]]
        hometeam = f['h']['Name']
        awayteam = f['a']['Name']
        scoresdict = getpoints(scoresdict, preds, hometeam, awayteam, winningmargin)
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    # todo; Can all of the logic be done in cypher??
    with tag('div', klass='row'):
        with tag('div', klass='container col s12 offset-m2  m8 offset-l2 l4'):
            with tag("table", klass='centred', style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px;"):
                with tag("thead"):
                    with tag("th"):
                        text("Name")
                    with tag("th"):
                        text("Score")
                with tag("tbody"):
                    scoreslist = []
                    for name, score in scoresdict.items():
                        scoreslist.append([name, score])
                        scoreslist.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True)
                    for apair in scoreslist:
                        with tag("tr"):
                            if apair[0] == username:
                                doc.attr(klass="lime lighten-5")
                            with tag("td"):
                                text(apair[0])
                            with tag("td"):
                                text(apair[1])
    innerhtml = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    return materialize(addmenu(innerhtml))

def spread(username):
    # todo: Home and away sections should be done via a function as is duplicating a lot of code there
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    usersleague = Neo.getuserleague(username)
    fixture, spreadpredictions = Neo.getspreadfixture(usersleague)
    if fixture is None:
        return materialize(addmenu("<center>No games have kicked off yet"), "")
    spreadpredictions = [[x['u']['Username'], x['t']['Name'], x['p']['Margin']] for x in spreadpredictions]
    hometeam = fixture['h']['Name']
    awayteam = fixture['a']['Name']
    maxhome = max([int(x[2]) for x in spreadpredictions if x[1] == hometeam] + [1])
    maxaway = max([int(x[2]) for x in spreadpredictions if x[1] == awayteam] + [1])
    with tag("center"):
        first = True
        for x in range(maxhome, 0, -1):
            with tag("div", klass="row reducemargin"):
                winners = getclosest(spreadpredictions, hometeam, awayteam, x * -1)
                if not winners:
                    winners = "No Winners"
                else:
                    winners = ', '.join(winners)
                if first:
                    addtext = "+"
                    first = False
                else:
                    addtext = ""
                text(hometeam + ' by ' + str(x) + addtext + ' : ' + winners)
        with tag("div", klass="row reducemargin"):
            text("Draw then nobody wins")
        first = True
        for x in range(1, maxaway + 1, 1):
            with tag("div", klass="row reducemargin"):
                winners = getclosest(spreadpredictions, hometeam, awayteam, x)
                if not winners:
                    winners = "No Winners"
                else:
                    winners = ', '.join(winners)
                if first:
                    addtext = "+"
                    first = False
                else:
                    addtext = ""
                text(awayteam + ' by ' + str(x) + addtext + ' : ' + winners)
    innerhtml = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    with tag('style'):
        doc.asis("div.reducemargin {margin-bottom: 2px;} ")
    css = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    return materialize(addmenu(innerhtml), css)

def predictions(username):
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    datenow = datetime.now()
    # datenow = datetime.strptime('01/02/2020 14:16', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    allfixtures = Neo.generateficturetable(username)
    allfixtures.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x["f"]["Date"] + ' ' + x["f"]["Time"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
    allfixtures = (x for x in allfixtures
                   if datetime.strptime(x["f"]["Date"] + ' ' + x["f"]["Time"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") > datenow)
    valueadjustorjs = []
    for thisfictureinfo in allfixtures:
        fixtureid = thisfictureinfo["f"]["GameID"]
        hometeam = thisfictureinfo["h"]["Name"]
        awayteam = thisfictureinfo["a"]["Name"]
        homecolour = thisfictureinfo["h"]["PrimaryColour"]
        awaycolour = thisfictureinfo["a"]["PrimaryColour"]
        hometext = thisfictureinfo["h"]["SecondaryColour"] + '-text'
        awaytext = thisfictureinfo["a"]["SecondaryColour"] + "-text"
        gamedate = thisfictureinfo["f"]["Date"]
        gametime = thisfictureinfo["f"]["Time"]
        gamedate = datetime.strptime(gamedate, "%d/%m/%Y")
        gametimeformatted = gamedate.strftime("%A %d %B")
        if thisfictureinfo["p"] is None:
            predictiontext = "No Prediction"
            margin = 0
        else:
            margin = thisfictureinfo["p"]["Margin"]
            predictedteam = thisfictureinfo["w"]["Name"]
            predictiontext = predictedteam + " to win by " + margin + ' points'
            if predictedteam == hometeam:
                margin = int(margin) * -1
            js = '$("#' + "Fixture-" + fixtureid + '-Slider").value = ' + str(margin) + "; "
            valueadjustorjs.append(js)
        with tag('center'):
            with tag('div', klass='row'):
                text("")
            with tag('div', klass='row'):
                text(gametimeformatted + ' ' + gametime)
            with tag('div', klass='row'):
                klasstext = 'waves-effect waves-light btn team ' + homecolour.lower() + ' ' + hometext.lower()
                with tag('a', klass=klasstext, id="Home-" + fixtureid):
                    text(hometeam)
                with tag('a', klass='waves-effect waves-light btn grey'):
                    text("V")
                klasstext = 'waves-effect waves-light btn team ' + awaycolour.lower() + ' ' + awaytext.lower()
                with tag('a', klass=klasstext, id="Away-" + fixtureid):
                    text(awayteam)
            with tag('div', klass='row biggertext', id="PredictionText-" + fixtureid):
                text(predictiontext)
            with tag('div', klass='row reducemargin'):
                # with tag('div'):
                with tag('form', action="#", klass='col s10 offset-s1 offset-m3 m6 offset-l4  l4 myslider'):
                    with tag('p', klass="range-field adjustup"):
                        doc.stag('input', type="range", id="Fixture-" + fixtureid + "-Slider", min="-60", max="60",
                                 value=margin)
    with tag('script'):
        doc.asis(gettextfromfile('debounce.js'))
        doc.asis(gettextfromfile('predictions.js'))
        for js in valueadjustorjs:
            doc.asis(js)
    innerhtml = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    with tag('style'):
        doc.asis("p.adjustup { position: relative; top: -28px;} ")
        doc.asis("a.team { width: 100px;} ")
        doc.asis("div.biggertext {font-size: large;} ")
        doc.asis("form.myslider {height: 17px;} ")
        doc.asis("div.reducemargin {margin-bottom: 14px;} ")
    css = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    return materialize(addmenu(innerhtml), css)

def results(username):
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    usersleague = Neo.getuserleague(username)
    datenow = datetime.now()
    # datenow = datetime.strptime('01/02/2020 14:16', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    allfixtures = Neo.generateresultstable()
    allfixtures.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x["f"]["Date"] + ' ' + x["f"]["Time"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
    allfixtures = (x for x in allfixtures
                   if datetime.strptime(x["f"]["Date"] + ' ' + x["f"]["Time"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") < datenow)
    valueadjustorjs = []
    for thisfictureinfo in allfixtures:
        fixtureid = thisfictureinfo["f"]["GameID"]
        hometeam = thisfictureinfo["h"]["Name"]
        awayteam = thisfictureinfo["a"]["Name"]
        homecolour = thisfictureinfo["h"]["PrimaryColour"]
        awaycolour = thisfictureinfo["a"]["PrimaryColour"]
        hometext = thisfictureinfo["h"]["SecondaryColour"] + '-text'
        awaytext = thisfictureinfo["a"]["SecondaryColour"] + "-text"
        homepoints = thisfictureinfo["f"]["HomePoints"]
        awaypoints = thisfictureinfo["f"]["AwayPoints"]
        margin = int(awaypoints) - int(homepoints)
        gamedate = thisfictureinfo["f"]["Date"]
        gametime = thisfictureinfo["f"]["Time"]
        gamedate = datetime.strptime(gamedate, "%d/%m/%Y")
        gametimeformatted = gamedate.strftime("%A %d %B")
        if margin < 0:
            winningteam = hometeam
        elif margin > 0:
            winningteam = awayteam
        else:
            winningteam = "Match ended in a draw"
        if margin != 0:
            predictiontext = winningteam + " won by " + str(abs(margin)) + " points"
        else:
            predictiontext = winningteam
        js = '$("#' + "Fixture-" + fixtureid + '-Slider").value = ' + str(margin) + "; "
        valueadjustorjs.append(js)
        with tag('center'):
            with tag('div', klass='row'):
                text("")
            with tag('div', klass='row'):
                text(gametimeformatted + ' ' + gametime)
            with tag('div', klass='row'):
                klasstext = 'waves-effect waves-light btn team ' + homecolour.lower() + ' ' + hometext.lower()
                with tag('a', klass=klasstext, id="Home-" + fixtureid):
                    text(hometeam)
                with tag('a', klass='waves-effect waves-light btn grey'):
                    text("V")
                klasstext = 'waves-effect waves-light btn team ' + awaycolour.lower() + ' ' + awaytext.lower()
                with tag('a', klass=klasstext, id="Away-" + fixtureid):
                    text(awayteam)
            with tag('div', klass='row biggertext', id="PredictionText-" + fixtureid):
                text(predictiontext)
            with tag('div', klass='row reducemargin'):
                # with tag('div'):
                with tag('form', action="#", klass='col s10 offset-s1 offset-m3 m6 offset-l4  l4 myslider'):
                    with tag('p', klass="range-field adjustup"):
                        doc.stag('input', type="range", id="Fixture-" + fixtureid + "-Slider", min="-60", max="60",
                                 value=margin)
    with tag('script'):
        doc.asis(gettextfromfile('results.js'))
        for js in valueadjustorjs:
            doc.asis(js)
        text(" ")
        if usersleague != 'Anytime':
            doc.asis(gettextfromfile('hideallsliders.js'))
    innerhtml = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    with tag('style'):
        doc.asis("p.adjustup { position: relative; top: -28px;} ")
        doc.asis("a.team { width: 100px;} ")
        doc.asis("div.biggertext {font-size: large;} ")
        doc.asis("form.myslider {height: 17px;} ")
        doc.asis("div.reducemargin {margin-bottom: 14px;} ")
    css = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    return materialize(addmenu(innerhtml), css)

def login():
    doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()
    with tag('center'):
        with tag('div', klass='row'):
            text('')
        with tag('h2'):
            text("McGarr's Six Nations Table Generator")
        with tag('div', klass='row'):
            with tag('div', klass='input-field col s6 offset-m2 offset-l4 m4 l2'):
                doc.stag('input', placeholder='Username', id='username', type='text')
            with tag('div', klass='input-field col s6 m4 l2'):
                doc.stag('input', placeholder='Password', id='password', type='password')
        with tag('div', klass='row'):
            with tag('a', klass='waves-effect waves-light btn', id='loginbutton'):
                text('Login')
        with tag('div', id='warningModal', klass='modal'):
            with tag('div', klass='modal-content'):
                with tag('h4', id='errorMessage'):
                    text('This is an error message')
            with tag('div', klass='modal-footer'):
                with tag('a', hred='#!', klass='modal-close'):
                    text("Close")
    with tag('script', src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js'):
        text('')
    with tag('script'):
        doc.asis(gettextfromfile('login.js'))
    innerHTML = indent(doc.getvalue(), indent_text=True)
    return materialize(innerHTML)
```

GameLogic.py  -- contains logic for working out which users get points

```py
def getclosest(spreadpredictions, hometeam, awayteam, x):
    mindiff = 1000
    closest = []
    for pred in spreadpredictions:
        user = pred[0]
        team = pred[1]
        margin = pred[2]
        testmargin = x
        if x < 0:
            winningteam = hometeam
            testmargin *= -1
        elif x > 0:
            winningteam = awayteam
        else:
            return []
        diff = abs(testmargin - int(margin))
        if team == winningteam and diff < mindiff:
            mindiff = diff
            texttoadd = user
            if diff == 0:
                texttoadd += '***'
            closest = [texttoadd]
        elif team == winningteam and diff == mindiff:
            texttoadd = user
            if diff == 0:
                texttoadd += '***'
            closest.append(texttoadd)
    return closest

def getpoints(scoresdict, spreadpredictions, hometeam, awayteam, winningmargin):
    mindiff = 1000
    closest = []
    exact = []
    for pred in spreadpredictions:
        user = pred[0]
        team = pred[1]
        margin = pred[2]
        testmargin = winningmargin
        if winningmargin < 0:
            winningteam = hometeam
            testmargin *= -1
        elif winningmargin > 0:
            winningteam = awayteam
        else:
            return scoresdict
        diff = abs(testmargin - int(margin))
        if team == winningteam and diff < mindiff:
            mindiff = diff
            texttoadd = user
            if diff == 0:
                exact = [user]
            closest = [texttoadd]
        elif team == winningteam and diff == mindiff:
            texttoadd = user
            if diff == 0:
                exact.append(user)
            closest.append(texttoadd)
        if team == winningteam:
            scoresdict[user] += 2
    for c in closest:
        scoresdict[c] += 3
    for e in exact:
        scoresdict[e] += 5
    return scoresdict
```

debouncer.js  -- prevents a function from firing too many times in a short space of time

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

login.js  -- login script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#warningModal').modal();
  });



$("#loginbutton").click(function(){
  usernameform = $("#username").val();
  passwordform = $("#password").val();
  if(!usernameform || !passwordform)
    {
      $('#errorMessage').text('How do you expect to login without entering both a username and a password? you dumb ass')
      $('#warningModal').modal('open');
    }
    else
    {
      $.ajax(
        {
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/loginsubmit",
          data : {'username': usernameform, 'password': passwordform},
          success: function(url){
            if(url != "Error")
            {
              window.location = url;
            }
            else {
              $('#errorMessage').text('Concentrate, you feeble minded fool and try again')
              $('#warningModal').modal('open');
            }
          }
        }
      )
    }
});
```

prediction.js  -- creates sliders and events for predictions

```
function addmouseup(fixtureid){
  sliderid = "Fixture-" + fixtureid + "-Slider"
  $('#' + sliderid).on('mouseup touchend' , debounce(function(){
      relfixtureid = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]
      homeid = "Home-" + relfixtureid
      awayid = "Away-" + relfixtureid
      predtextid = "PredictionText-" + relfixtureid
      hometeam = $('#' + homeid).html().trim()
      awayteam = $('#' + awayid).html().trim()
      margin = $(this).val()
      if(margin <= 0){
        teamprediction = hometeam
        margin = margin * -1
      }
      else {
        teamprediction = awayteam
      }
      $.ajax(
        {
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/PredictionSubmit",
          data : {'ateam': teamprediction, 'afixtureid': relfixtureid, 'margin': margin},
          error: function(){
            alert("Prediction Submission Error - Please tell McGarr");
          },
          success: function(msg){
            if(msg=="Cheat"){
              alert("Nice try! You cheating!")
              location.reload();
            }
            if(msg=="Failure"){
              alert("You are not logged in correctly")
              location.reload();
            }
          }
        }
      )

  }, 429));
  $('#' + sliderid).on('input' , function(){
    relfixtureid = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]
    homeid = "Home-" + relfixtureid
    awayid = "Away-" + relfixtureid
    predtextid = "PredictionText-" + relfixtureid
    hometeam = $('#' + homeid).html().trim()
    awayteam = $('#' + awayid).html().trim()
    margin = $(this).val()
    if(margin <= 0){
      teamprediction = hometeam
      margin = margin * -1
    }
    else {
      teamprediction = awayteam
    }
    $('#' + predtextid).text(teamprediction + ' to win by ' + margin + ' points')
  })
}

for (i=1;i < 16; i++){
  addmouseup(i.toString());
}
```

results.js

```
function addmouseup(fixtureid){
  sliderid = "Fixture-" + fixtureid + "-Slider"
  $('#' + sliderid).on('mouseup touchend' , function(){
      relfixtureid = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]
      homeid = "Home-" + relfixtureid
      awayid = "Away-" + relfixtureid
      hometeam = $('#' + homeid).html().trim()
      awayteam = $('#' + awayid).html().trim()
      margin = $(this).val()
      $.ajax(
        {
          type: 'POST',
          url: "/ResultSubmit",
          data : {'afixtureid': relfixtureid, 'margin': margin},
          error: function(){
            alert("Result Submission Error - Please tell McGarr");
          },
          success: function(msg){
            if(msg=="Failure"){
              alert("You are not logged in correctly")
              location.reload();
            }
          }
        }
      )

  });
  $('#' + sliderid).on('input' , function(){
    relfixtureid = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]
    predtextid = "PredictionText-" + relfixtureid
    homeid = "Home-" + relfixtureid
    awayid = "Away-" + relfixtureid
    hometeam = $('#' + homeid).html().trim()
    awayteam = $('#' + awayid).html().trim()
    margin = $(this).val()
    if(margin < 0){
      teamprediction = hometeam
      margin = margin * -1
    }
    else if (margin > 0) {
      teamprediction = awayteam
    }
    else {

    }
    $('#' + predtextid).text(teamprediction + ' won by ' + margin + ' points')
  })
}

for (i=1;i < 16; i++){
  addmouseup(i.toString());
}
```

hideallsliders.js

```
var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("range-field"); //divsToHide is an array
for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++){
    divsToHide[i].style.visibility = "hidden"; 
}
```

Comment: For the unenlightened people among us (like me): You're talking about [rugby](https://www.sixnationsrugby.com/fixtures-2020/), right?

Comment: I am yes, the tournament is happening now